# How can i remove selected video from screen with button Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, picker

I want to remove selected video from the screen, I tried different ways but could not get it here is the code :

there is button on video frame so when i click i want to remove from screen

```
if (_video != null) {
  _videoPlayerController.value.initialized
    ? Expanded(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 45,
              width: 47,
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio:
                  _videoPlayerController
                      .value
                      .aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(
                  _videoPlayerController
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: -15,
              right: -15,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                child: IconButton(
                  hoverColor: Colors.red,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.delete,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    size: 23,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => _removeVideo
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    : Container()
} else {
  Text(" ",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
  ),
}


_pickVideo() async {
  File video = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  _video = video;
  _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(_video)
    ..initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {});
// _videoPlayerController.play();
    });
  }
```

this what i tried, i created function but its not working

```
void _removeVideo() {
  _video.remove(_video);
  setState(() {
    _video = _video;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you should only need to do this:

```
void _removeVideo() {
  setState(() {
    _video = null;
  });
}
```

Comment: Then your issue is elsewhere in your code. You have a check for the `_video` variable to see if it's null. If you use setState to set it as null, then the container should appear instead of the video. If that isn't working, the problem is somewhere else.